# Delphi memory leak with pointer to TStringList

Tags: delphi, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm having a little trouble understanding the behaviour of pointers.
I have a very simple example to demonstrate:

```
type
  PSL = ^TStringList;
...
var
  myPSL : PSL;
...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  New(myPSL);
  myPSL^ := TStringList.Create;
  myPSL^.Add('String 1');
  myPSL^.Add('String 2');
  myPSL^.Add('String 3');
end;
...
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Dispose(myPSL);
end;
```

With this code I get this memory leak report

```
29 - 36 bytes: UnicodeString x 3
37 - 44 bytes: Unknown x 1
85 - 92 bytes: TStringList x 1
```

Now, if I call

```
myPSL^.Free;
```

before disposing of the pointer, then nothing is reported.

I can't understand why this is happening. I know that calling **New()** allocates enough memory (based on the type of the pointer) and calling **Dispose()** takes care for deallocating that same memory, then why do I need **Free** the pointer as if it was a "real" object?

Thanks!

Comment: What tutorial were you following that got you into this mess in the first place?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Class objects are already referenced by  pointer. It makes very little sense to define a pointer to a reference type. Just use the type directly:

```
var
  myPSL : TStringList;
...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myPSL := TStringList.Create;
  myPSL.Add('String 1');
  myPSL.Add('String 2');
  myPSL.Add('String 3');
end;
...
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myPSL.Free;
end;
```

What your code actually does is following:

`New(myPSL)` and `Dispose(myPSL)` are simply allocating/deallocating a memory block that is `sizeof(TStringList)` bytes in size, but are not actually constructing/destructing the `TStringList` object within that memory. You need to call `myPSL := TStringList.Create` and `myPSL.Free` for that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to store pointer to `TStringList`, instance of `TStringList` is actually also pointer. To solve it, change type of `myPSL` to something like below:

```
var
   myPSL : TStringList;
...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myPSL := TStringList.Create;
  myPSL.Add('String 1');
  myPSL.Add('String 2');
  myPSL.Add('String 3');
end;
...
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myPSL.Free;
end;
```

If somehow, you still need to use your old code, to avoid memory leak, you need to call `Free` before you dispose `myPSL`:

```
myPSL^.Free;
dispose(myPSL);
```